# Gatsbyjs + Google analytics - tracking custom events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, event-handling, gatsby

Is it somehow possible to track custom events with gatsby and google analytics?

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: A simple example would be - I have a list of entries, each one has some "algorithm" attached. When user selects an entry I want to track the algorithm to understand which one is the most used

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used [ReactGA](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) in conjunction with Gatsby and had good success.

For basic event tracking - like logging a clicked link - it's very easy to use. You create a logging function in your component that accesses `ReactGA.event` and then invoke it in your render function using `onClick`.

Example component logging a PDF download:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

import logo from './logo.png'
import financials from './Annual_Report_Financials_2017_FINAL.pdf'

class LoggingDownload extends React.Component {
  logger() {
    // Detect each click of the financial PDF
    ReactGA.event({
      category: 'Financial Download',
      action: 'User clicked link to view financials'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="nav-container">
          <Link to="/locations">
            <img className="logo" src={logo} alt="Logo" />
          </Link>
          <ul className="nav-item-container">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a href="/shortsignup/" target="_blank">Join Us</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a href={financials} onClick={this.logger} target="_blank" id="financials-pdf">Financials</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default LoggingDownload
```

There are tons more use cases - check out ReactGA docs.

Also: don't forget to include `ggatsby-plugin-google-analytics` in your `gatsby-config.js` file as a dependency to getting the above to work correctly:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
  options: {
    trackingId: "UA-#########-##",
    // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
    head: false,
    // Setting this parameter is optional
    respectDNT: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. So basically gatsby plugin takes over analytics setup and then ReactGA just works without any setup?

Comment: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` inserts GA into the end of the body of your site automatically, so basic pageviews are easily tracked that way. And if you need event tracking, outbound links, that's where I've used `react-ga`. I think you could setup pageview tracking without `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` if you wanted a very slightly cleaner dependency chain.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone who is still wondering, `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` is **not** the  approach I would take for google analytics. What you are looking for is [gatsby-plugin-google-gtag](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/). This plugin automatically sends pageviews, as well as makes the `gtag` event available on the window.

```
window.gtag("event", "click", { ...data })
```

Google also gives us migration docs for anyone who is still using `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration.) (link also in the gatsby docs).

Comment: This one looks better, I spend15 minutes every time I need to add analytics to ensure that `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` is not what I am looking for. It does not even states that analytics only works in production, while `gtag` clearly defines that with big `NOTE` wording. Love it so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the provided OutboundLink for simple link tracking:

```js
import React from "react"
import { OutboundLink } from "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag"

export default () => (
  <div>
    <OutboundLink href="https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/">
      Visit the Google Global Site Tag plugin page!
    </OutboundLink>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Where to look for this OutboundLink in the Analytics Dashboard? I mean I can see page-views in the dashboard but click events or link clicks are not defined there, where can i check those?

Comment: Had the same issue. Perhaps default GA4 only allows for seeing outbound events in real-time or the last 30 min. Might need to manually do a gtag push and do a custom event.