# Why is gatsby-plugin-google-gtag not working in Gatsby with the Measurement ID?

Tags: google-analytics, environment-variables, gatsby, github-pages, github-secret

With Gatsby 4.18.0 I've added the plugin [`gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/) and in Google Analytics I've created a **Property**.

After selecting **Web** I'm prompted with:

```
STREAM NAME: Foo Bar
STREAM URL: https://foorbar.com
STREAM ID: ###########
MEASUREMENT ID: G-#######
```

*gatsby-config.js*:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
  options: {
    trackingIds: [
      process.env.GOOGLE_GTAG,
    ],
    pluginConfig: {
      head: false,
    },
  },
},
```

Hosting with [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) I go to S**ettings > Secrets > Actions**. Create a <kbd>New repository secret</kbd> and:

```
Name: GOOGLE_GTAG
Value: the Measurement ID
```

After saving these settings I then commit to the branch and run a script command:

```
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public -b gh-pages"
},
```

Indicated in the terminal a **Published** and I've waited a few hours. When I check the `view-source` I see a `null`:

```
<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=null"></script>
```

### Research

- [Why does gatsby-plugin-google-gtag includes analytics.js and gtag.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60672789/why-does-gatsby-plugin-google-gtag-includes-analytics-js-and-gtag-js)
- [How use gatsby-plugin-google-gtag with Gatsby.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943144/how-use-gatsby-plugin-google-gtag-with-gatsby-js)
- [How to Add multiple Tracking ID for Google Analytics in Gatsby.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70796727/how-to-add-multiple-tracking-id-for-google-analytics-in-gatsby-js)
- [Gatsbyjs + Google analytics - tracking custom events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53054636/gatsbyjs-google-analytics-tracking-custom-events/55283866#55283866)
- [How to use environment variables in Github Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648652/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-github-page)

This is my first time trying the plugin and hosting with Github Pages but what am I doing wrong and how can I get Google Analytics to work in Gatsby?

---

In response to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73330103/1952287) if I build out a workflow with the suggested target to main branch:

```
name: Environment Variables
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run-script build
        env:
          GOOGLE_ADSENSE: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_ADSENSE }}
          GOOGLE_GTAG: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_GTAG }}
```

it throws an error from what I assume to re-building after I've already ran the command:

```
npm run deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expose first the variables to your GitHub CI action to make the secret available, using your own action or using a created one (like https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gatsby-publish).

In both cases, you will end up mapping your secrets with the environment variable name inside the `env` like:

```
- uses: enriikke/gatsby-gh-pages-action@v2
  with:
    access-token: ${{ secrets.GH_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
    deploy-branch: gh-pages
    gatsby-args: --prefix-paths
  env:
    GOOGLE_GTAG: ${{secrets.GOOGLE_GTAG}}
```

Or as the [How to use environment variables in Github Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648652/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-github-page) that you mention suggests:

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run-script build
      env:
        REACT_APP_APIKey: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_APIKey }}
        REACT_APP_APISecret: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_APISecret }}
```

Tweak the running commands to match yours, of course.